# JavasCript function fails to start even though top value is the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have a dropdown menu that works when button is clicked, and its supposed to go `top = 0` when opened and `top = -50%` when closed, so it stay hidden above the page, but the problem is I have to click the button twice until the JS sets the top value, even though the top value in the CSS style is the same as the one stated in the script.

CSS:

```
 .sidenav {
 position: fixed;
 top: -50%;
 left: 0;
 height: 250px;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: white;
 overflow:hidden;
 transition: 0.3s;
 padding-top: 80px;
 box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }
```

Html:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="itens">
    <a href="#">Program</a>
    <a href="#">Program</a>
    <a href="#">Program</a>
    <a href="#">Program</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggleNav() {
    var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
        if (element.style.top == "-50%") {
            element.style.top = "0";
        } else {
            element.style.top = "-50%";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your element does not have a `style.top` set. Your function does it on first click. The rule in your css is not the same as `style.top`. So just give it an initial value:

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.top = '-50%';

function toggleNav() {
  var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  if (element.style.top == "-50%") {
    element.style.top = "0";
  } else {
    element.style.top = "-50%";
  }
}
```

Comment: ok so those are different from the style, thats good to know, thanks for your help!